# What does "I called him mine" mean?

Tags: expressions

In a popular song, "My Baby Shot Me Down", the text contains this expression:

> When I grew up *I called him mine*

What does it mean?

Comment: It's not an expression which has a firm fixed meaning - so like a lot of song lyrics, you can read into it whatever you want to. For what it's worth, I've always interpreted it as meaning that the two childhood friends grew up to be life partners (got married, perhaps). That's one context in which you might call someone "yours" - but I'm sure there are others, and a different person with different life experiences might read something different into the same lyrics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember when we were kids?

[image]

The lyrics of the song *[Bang Bang](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tdn4otwyy7dtchbkt4vksd2ei4m?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics)*, by Nancy Sinatra, suggest that she became the **steady girlfriend** of her childhood friend and eventually married him, but the pattern of their relationship never changed from their childish game:

> I was five and he was six
>   We rode on horses made of sticks
>   He wore
>   black and I wore white
>   He would always win the fight
>
> **Chorus:**
>   Bang bang, he shot me down
>   Bang bang, I hit the ground
>   Bang bang, that
>   awful sound
>   Bang bang, my baby shot me down
>
> Seasons came and changed the time
>   **When I grew up, I called him mine**
>   He
>   would always laugh and say
>   "Remember when we used to play?"
>
> **Chorus:**
>
> Music played and people sang
>   Just for me the church bells rang
>
> Now
>   he's gone, I don't know why
>   And 'till this day, sometimes I cry
>   He
>   didn't even say goodbye
>   He didn't take the time to lie
>
> **Chorus:**

Comment: So it is equivalent to "When I grew up, I began to call him my husband", isn't it?

Comment: There seems to be a "progression of possession" between English speaking boys and girls, friends...dates...steady girl/boyfriends, spouse. In the immediate context of this song, the possessive "mine" seem to indicate ***steady boyfriend***. The church bells were the metaphor to indicate the spouse level.